# Why my classifier is unable to learn postive classes?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm currently performing classification, but my classifier is unable to predict postive classes on test set.

The positive to negative distribution is 10:90. I did a 5 fold cross-validation using stratified sampling, the results seems to be continuous across all folds, while the in test it predicts all classes as positive.

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier

scores =[]
clf1 = XGBClassifier() 
clf1.fit(X,y)
scores = cross_val_score(clf1, X, y, cv=skf.split(X, y), scoring='roc_auc')
print(scores.mean())
scores
```

The output of the same is

```
0.6286471235534742
array([0.62958638, 0.63038406, 0.6277138 , 0.63027538, 0.62527601])
```

I have treated my categorical data as on-hot encoding. The test class distribution is 14:86. It is predicting all classes as negative.

My training dataset size is 75002,44.

Answer (score 0):

The aim of using roc_auc as a scoring/evaluating function is not predicting negative and positive classes with the threshold 0.5 but the rank of probabilities that the prediction is of the positive class. Mean probability of predicted values is usually equal to the ratio of number of possitive class to the total number, so in the case of small positive class ratio and small roc_auc (0.6x is rather small), all predicted values may group around the mean probability (~0.10-0.15) suggesting there is no possitive class. You should change the evaluating function if you need  what roc_auc doesn't offer.

Comment: I tried the same with f1 also, but didn't get any improvement

Comment: AUC equal 0.6x shows that your model is far from optimal. That is why the change of evaluating function makes no improvement. You should perform feature engineering and optimization of XGBoost hyperparameters.